# How to add oath to phpmailer.php

Tags: php

I have downloaded PHPMailer zip from guthub and have a working script (which even sends to my gmail friends).

I also have obtained an OATH token ( ID/Secret and json ).

There are some associated files that seem to do with security but there is insufficient explanation (for me!) to see how to apply the token to any of the scripts

Can anyone advise how I can modify the script to configure my oath token?

Please?

My send routine fails with the following initial lines:

```
    //require '../vendor/autoload.php'; zip came with this - but there is no folder supplied called vendor?
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
require "PHPMailer/get_oauth_token.php";
require "PHPMailer/phpmaileroauth.php";    

function smtpmailer($to, $emailcustomer, $namecustomer, $subject, $body)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
      //   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = phpmaileroauth::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
```

But passes with the following:

```
//require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
// require "PHPMailer/get_oauth_token.php";
// require "PHPMailer/phpmaileroauth.php";

function smtpmailer($to, $emailcustomer, $namecustomer, $subject, $body)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
      //   $mail->SMTPSecure = phpmaileroauth::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
```

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what you mean. Please provide more context and explain more specifically what you want to achieve and why. Take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up you ADyson